# Anybody knows how to embed UWP/WPF in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, embed

I am building a disability service in Unity that will let paralyzed people move mouse cursor with their head movement only. Whatever is in Unity is just a function so im wondering if its possible to embed it in UWP software.

So someone would launch UWP software, click on "Start Unity" button and then the software would wrap itself into unity and function is now accessible (embedded software is clickable). There are a few examples of embedding browsers in Unity (example below), but can this be done with a software. Assuming I have access to software's code.

[image: Browser example]

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about integrating UWP app in Unity, but there are sources about how to do it other way around, maybe you can follow them and see if you scenario is possible. You can start with [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/15/unity-interop-and-app-extensibility-app-dev-on-xbox-series/#w1l2Pl8MV5TaC31y.97) and [realted github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/uwp-experiences/tree/master/apps/weather), maybe even open an issue there to ask your question. Other articles available if you search for "unity uwp interop".

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin Thank you! I actually came across Atmosphere. Didnt try it out yet, was looking for something exactly the opposite of that. XAML below Unity engine. Thank you for the "interop" tip and github link!